# Prove that $8(5)^n+6(3)^{2n}−80n−14$ is divisible by $512$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by induction.

Tags: induction, divisibility

we need to Prove that $8(5)^n+6(3)^{2n}−80n−14$ is divisible by $512$ for all n∈N by induction.

I started by base case $n = 1$.
Then I took for $k$.
Not able to prove true for $k+1$. Please help.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: No, *we* don't need to prove the proposition, *you* do.

Comment: I tried but can't do it

Comment: The key to these problems is to figure out what the $n=k+1$ case has to do with the $n=k$ case.  One possibility is that the expression when $n=k+1$ is divisible by the expression when $n=k$.  That looks difficult here because we have a sum of terms.  Another possibility is that the difference of the expressions is divisible by $512$.  That looks much more approachable.

Comment: Can we show difference as divisible by 512. Will it mean that the expression is divisible by 521?

Comment: Hint: since the exponential terms are proportional to the roots $5,\,9$ of $\lambda^2-14\lambda+45$, simplify $a_{n+2}-14a_{n+1}+45a_n$, then take an inductive step $a_k,\,a_{k+1}$ to $a_{k+1},\,a_{k+2}$.

Comment: This is a tougher more interesting problem than the OP is given credit for so far here.

Comment: Please don't duplicate (your?) prior questions.